# Change height of UIView with autolayout turned off

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, resize

Turned off auto layout for the view. However this doesn't work. I have no restraints regarding height. Only width that equal parent views width.

```
@IBOutlet weak var questionTextView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  var newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 202)
  questionView.frame = newFrame
}
```

Comment: for me it works! make sure that you connected the outlet and also call `super.viewDidLoad()` at the beginning of your `viewDidLoad` implementation!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Did you turn off auto layout for the entire nib in interface builder?

You can't turn off auto layout for specific sub-views in interface builder - you can only do it at runtime programmatically.

Based on what you said you still have a constraint active. How do you have constraints when you've turned off auto layout already?

If you have auto layout active, setting the height for your view by using the frame won't work since it'll conflict with auto layout rules.

If you need to change the height of a view with auto layout active, you'll need to create an `IBOutlet` for your height constraint and modify that at runtime, i.e.:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

self.heightConstraint.constant = 200
```

Comment: The constraint method worked great. Thanks for clarifying about the auto layout.

Comment: Nice solution you deserve it. I was trying the change a height of uiview in a easy way, not like creating a frame, and then assign a frame, and your solution fitted well to my needs.

Comment: This solution works like a charm for me in iOS 8, Xcode 7.2 too. I use this technique to free the real estate taken by the iad banner when it doesn't receive ads. I do it by changing height constraint to 1.

Comment: @mmilo Can you please ELI5 me how to create the heightConstraint exactly?! I can't find any option in interface builder to add constraint for the actual View! The constraint options are disabled. I need to resize the height of the whole view (and not specific sub-view). Xcode 7.3.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**[edited]**

ps. As the accepted answer says: `If you have auto layout active, setting the height for your view by using the frame won't work since it'll conflict with auto layout rules`. This peace of code changes the frame, so if you are trying to use this code with Auto Layout, it won't work.

---

**[original answer]**

You could also create a UIView Extension:

**UIViewExtensions.swift** :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    // MARK: - Frame

    /**
    Redefines the height of the view

    :param: height The new value for the view's height
    */
    func setHeight(height: CGFloat) {

        var frame: CGRect = self.frame
        frame.size.height = height

        self.frame = frame
    }

    /**
    Redefines the width of the view

    :param: width The new value for the view's width
    */
    func setWidth(width: CGFloat) {

        var frame: CGRect = self.frame
        frame.size.width = width

        self.frame = frame
    }

    /**
    Redefines X position of the view

    :param: x The new x-coordinate of the view's origin point
    */
    func setX(x: CGFloat) {

        var frame: CGRect = self.frame
        frame.origin.x = x

        self.frame = frame
    }

    /**
    Redefines Y position of the view

    :param: y The new y-coordinate of the view's origin point
    */
    func setY(y: CGFloat) {

        var frame: CGRect = self.frame
        frame.origin.y = y

        self.frame = frame
    }
}
```

I also added methods for setting the width, X and Y. You can use that extension in any view you want like:

```
yourView.setHeght(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var someView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: **view.bounds.size.width**, height: 123))
        someView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
        view.addSubview(someView)
```

In your case change view with parent view.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, and by setting it to true, you can write your constraints through code without having to do other stuff.

Example: view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

// This code will work

```
view.frame = CGRect(x: self.playerChatBackground.frame.origin.x, y:                                     
self.playerChatBackground.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 36.0)
```